# Feature request "Mentor/Buddy" badges

Tags: feature-request, badges, badge-request

What do you think of a "Mentor" badge being awarded to a user who has helped the same poster numerous times? I.e. If a poster asks 10 questions and I answered all of these questions and received the accepted answer for each question I would be awarded the following badge:

"Mentor" being a gold badge for 25+ accepted answers for the same poster.

"Buddy" being a silver badge for 10+ accepted answers for the same poster.

Comment: Seems to encourage Socky behavior/favoritism.

Comment: @BenBrocka - if this were the case the OP of a question could just accept his favourite person each time regardless of a badge being rewarded.  The badge should indicate that a user has helped a person numerous of times out of good nature. If this were the case with other badges you could argue that the Sportsmanship badge is invalid due to people being encouraged to upvote other competing answers that lack quality in order to get a badge.

Comment: It's a valid suggestion, don't vote down to -7 :¬P

Comment: @alan: What do you mean by "valid"? Note that [votes are different on Meta](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/faq#vote-differences).

Comment: Thanks. You'r right. I'd forgotten about how votes are considered differently on the meta sites. Seemed a bit severe at the time.

Answer (score 14):

Stack Overflow (and Stack Exchange) is about questions and answers. It's not about you, me, or user271828.

This badge would encourage people to "follow" other people, which is not, in my opinion, the right behavior to promote.
Users should be looking for questions they can help with, not people they can assist.

Comment: I agree with what you say entirely, the badge would be novelty (as all badges are) to people who have helped ("Mentored") other users more than once.  As stated in my comment the badges on stack overflow such as Sportsmanship, Electorate encourage people to vote on questions and answers, however it does not stop people voting on questions that lack content and quality, which IMO also applies to the badge requested.

Comment: @DarrenDavies: The Sportsmanship badge encourages users that are competent enough in a topic to answer questions there to also go through/rate competing answers. This is a good thing for the site in general - good answers get more votes. Of course some people will do anything to get the badge - your proposal is not immune from that. But what good (for the site) behavior does your proposal promote that is not already covered by rep and answer-related badges?

Comment: I am not arguing that my badge is immune at all, I actually agree but the badges I have mentioned on here are susceptible to favouritism just as much as mine.  The badge I suggested is not designed to track/follow users, rather encourage/promote answering users questions and if you have happened to have helped that user previously you will be rewarded.  The people you mention (who will do anything to get the badge) are obviously not on the site for the correct reasons and are collecting the badges for self gain rather than the satisfaction of helping others.

Comment: Sportsmanship is not subject to favoritism (except in very low volume tags, but that can't be helped - and your badge has the same issue there). In what way, for Stack Overflow and "the Internet", is making 25 great answers to questions from one person any better than  if the questions were from 25 different people? Your badge does encourage focusing on users. Sportsmanship encourages voting on good answers, even if you're in the "competition" on a question.

Comment: from your answer you state that stack overflow is not about you, me or any other user.  If this was the case then why does Stack Overflow have a user profile, have statistics for the year, month, week and have a reputation system? IMO to allow a user to focus on other users and compete against them. If you actually look at some of the top users answers on SO in certain scenarios they get up voted immediately based on their reputation rather because they are a great answer.

Comment: Rep & badges are meant to keep people engaged in the site ("gamification"). That's all (well, that plus privileges you gain with your rep (interpreted as a measure of trust)). Some people might be out there trying to "beat" or surpass other users - that's fine as long as no underhanded tactics are used (and some automated measures are in place for that).

Comment: @Mat What do you have against [user314159](http://stackoverflow.com/users/314159/leachianus-gecko)? :P

Comment: @AndrewBarber: (: should have checked.